# Fixing AttributeError in VectorBT (vbt) when using IndicatorFactory and from_talib()

Tags: python, ta-lib

New to VectorBT (vbt) here, but already loving it!

I am practising creating custom indicators using IndicatorFactory and from_talib().
However, I get an error that I can't find how to fix...

Here is the code:

```
import vectorbt as vbt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import talib
from numba import njit


btc_price = vbt.YFData.download(symbols='BTC-GBP', period='100d', interval='1h').get("Close")

RSI = vbt.IndicatorFactory.from_talib('RSI')

@njit
def produce_signal(rsi, entry, exit):
trend = np.where(rsi > exit, -1, 0)
trend = np.where(rsi < entry, 1, trend)
return trend

def custom_indicator(close, rsi_window=14, entry=30, exit=70):
rsi = RSI.run(close, rsi_window).real.to_numpy()
return produce_signal(rsi, entry, exit)
ind = vbt.IndicatorFactory(
class_name="Combination",
short_name="comb",
input_names=["close"],
param_names=["rsi_window", "entry", "exit"],
output_names=["value"],
).from_apply_func(
custom_indicator,
rsi_window=14,
entry=30,
exit=70,
)

res = ind.run(btc_price,
rsi_window=np.arange(2, 40, step=2, dtype=int),
entry=np.arange(10, 40, step=2, dtype=int),
exit=np.arange(60, 90, step=2, dtype=int),
param_product = True
)

print(res.value)

entries = res.value == 1
exits = res.value == -1

pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(btc_price,
entries,
exits,
freq='1h',
sl_stop=[0.02],
sl_trail=True,
)

print(pf.stats())
pf.plot().show()
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/XXXXX/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/VectorBT test optimisation.py", line 41, in <module>
RSI = vbt.IndicatorFactory.from_talib('RSI')
File "/Users/XXXXX/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vectorbt/indicators/factory.py", line 3441, in from_talib
info = abstract.Function(func_name)._Functioninfo
AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute '_Functioninfo'. Did you mean: '_Function__name'?
```

I checked on various forums, but can't find anyone else with this error.
So probably related to my own code, but can't find where...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit your code such that it's using valid python indents.  Also, which version of vectorbt are you using?

Comment: code needs format

Comment: @ewokx: i have downgraded to vbt version 0.24, numpy 1.23.2, pandas 1.5.0 and numba 0.56.2, and all is well now!